# How to find maximum negative root of equations

Tags: c++

I need to write function for finding maximum negative root of the equation. And then include this module and use for exact f(x)= x^5 +3x^3+x^2+1, but not only for this.

So, 2 questions:

- 1) I use method od dichotomy, so I dont understand what I need to add to make my function find maximum negative x, even if we have interval (a,0).
- 2) I dont have infinum, so my program may never ends, I have only supremum x=0, since we work only with negative x, but how to find out exact interval? I think It must be connected with derivatives, but how...

Here is my function, func is pointer to function in main.cpp

```
const double epsilon=0.1;
double dichotomy(double infinum, double supremum,  double(*func)(double)) {
  double x;
  while (supremum - infinum > epsilon) {
    x = (infinum + supremum) / 2;
    if (func(supremum) * func(x) < 0)
      infinum = x;
    else
      supremum = x;
  }
  return (infinum + supremum) / 2;
}
```

Comment: yeah, minus it, but I have not found similar problems neither the solutions without given interval a,b

Comment: Why are you wondering that giving such an incomplete question (in contrary of providing a [mcve]) is downvoted?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what is unclear here? I said the task, said the trouble I faced and provided the code of my function which I must develop to find max negative root. Also I need to find out the exact interval to work with. I always feel like the object of scorn, but nobody still asks my simple questions, just minus it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good method to find the maximum negative real root for any arbitrary function. Your code seems to use some variation of binary search, though I'm not too sure what `func(supremum) * func(x)` is supposed to represent. In general, even for the example `f(x)= x^5 +3x^3+x^2+1` that you gave, binary search will not guarantee that you find the maximum negative real root. This is because the function is not monotonous. I don't believe you will be able to modify binary search to work with any arbitrary function. However, if you can restrict your function set to polynomials, there are algorithms which accomplish what you need. Refer to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64602/find-all-rational-roots-of-a-polynomial-equation for example. Moreover, you can also try to modify binary search in such ways as tertiary search to deal with all types of polynomials.

Comment: Is there any simple way to solve this, if we select interval manually?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can think of one algorithm. Given an interval, take as many random points within that interval. For each point, 'descend' from that point along the function until you hit a root. That is, for each point, get the derivative of the function at that point, and depending on its sign, move your search either left or right. Do this on each point until you find a root. Then, you can simply take the max of the negative roots you've found. To get the derivative at a point of the function, evaluate the function at small intervals around the point.